# Make Font Bold/Italic/Underline Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Ok I already have a Font Dialog that changes the font of the richtextbox and it works (although I don't know how to make the apply button of the dialog work)

I also made 4 buttons for Bold, Underline, Strikethrough, and Italic.

The method I have found most people using is

```
Dim boldf as NewFont(....)
```

and then applying it to the selected text.

Problem with that is that it changes the font to only Bold, it doesn't add it to the existing style.

Please advise.

Comment: Hard to guess what class library you are talking about.  The Winforms FontDialog already has a selection for the style but doesn't have an Apply button.  WPF doesn't have a font dialog.

Comment: FontDialog.ShowApply() brings in an apply dialog I just don't know how to access the apply button.

Comment: Must be Winforms then.  Just implement the Apply event handler.  Mystery number 2 is why you don't see the Style part of that dialog.  "Bold" is a one of the selections.

Comment: How would I implement the "Apply event handler" ? also I do see it and it's functioning. However this is another accessibility thing where I have a toolbar with a shortcut to the Bold, Italic, etc options (like in Microsoft Word) ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub andlowitwasbold_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles andlowitwasbold.Click
    If RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Bold Then 'its already bold, so set it to regular
        RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, RichTextBox1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular)
    Else 'make it bold
        RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, RichTextBox1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This does the same thing... If i set the font to size 72 and Courier New (Just and example) ... then press ok on the font dialog.. Leave and highlight the text and select the "Bold" button where the above code is used it overwrites everything and is only bold.

Comment: edited, as i misunderstood your question. It will now only effect the selected text

Comment: Oh ok so I guess the trick was to have SelectionFont for everything so that it takes whats already there and adds to it.

Comment: Just another note... I want when I click it again that it becomes "Un Bolded" .... so i made a counter and made it so when it's 0 it goes bold and adds 1, then if it =  1 then it subtracts 1 and "unbolds" however how do I "unbold"  ......... not FontStyle.Bold ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Bold = Not(RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Bold)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "Bold" property on a Font is Read Only.